# JavaMail Type mismatch: cannot convert from MimeBodyPart to BodyPart

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail

I get an error using the following code :

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
```

I've read the docs and MimeBodyPart implements the BodyPart interface, so what gives?  I'm using Java7, JavaMail 1.4.5 and Eclipse Juno.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I get an error"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/), `MimeBodyPart` implements only `MimePart` and `Part` (`MimePart` extends `Part`). Furthermore, `BodyPart` doesn't even seem to be an interface.

Comment: MimeBodyPart extends BodyPart (I mistyped their relationship above), so it seems like the code should work - any insight as to why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Totally my Bad - I had the wrong import for "BodyPart", so the inheritance wasn't correct.  Thanks for everyone's help